# Is there a simple way to generate similar colors?

Tags: colors

Given a color (in hex) I want to generate a set of colors that look almost exactly like the given color but are a little bit different. Is there a good way to do this other than just arbitrarily/randomly increasing or decreasing r g or b?

Thanks!

Comment: Can they be randomly different?  Why don't you want to just randomly change the r, b, or g components?

Comment: They can be randomly different. The reason I'm not sure about changing the r, g, and b components is that it seems like an equal change in those values doesn't produce equal results. So if I change the red component by say 30 it might not be very noticeable but if I change the blue component by 30 it makes a huge difference. I was wondering if there is a correct way to determine how much each value should be changed by or something. Maybe it's easiest to just fudge it though.

Comment: do you want it the same general color, but different shades?  It can be helpful to use a color picker with a scale to muck around with.  Also consider increasing/decreasing by the same percent instead of the same value.

Comment: I do need to do this programmatically and I do need the same color but  different shades. What I did was break the color up into it's r, g, and b components and then randomly alter those and then put those new components back together into a new color. It seems like this makes blues change more on average than reds for example but I'll try tweaking the random changes to each component to see what I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to do this programmatically (Sass/Compass can do it by multiplying/dividing a percentage of the hex value), or manually.

If manual, you can use this [online color palette](http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html).  It has a lighten/darken scheme and displays 16 colors at a time that are nearly identical.